# Blank app on Heroku: express.static and or res.sendFile issue?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, heroku

I uploaded a `React + Node + Express` app onto Heroku. The app was working locally but shows up as a blank screen once deployed. Console logs are not showing any errors.

Newbie here, so please bear with me.

I suspect, in server.js, I am going wrong with:

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  // Serve any static files
  app.use('client/public', express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/')));
  // Handle React routing, return all requests to React app
  app.get('*', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'client/public', 'index.html'));
      });
}
```

Our folder structure is a bit weird (we've been working off different tutorials). `/client/public/index.html` has the div where `/client/src/index.js` renders into. `App.js` holds the routes. I am wondering if `res.sendFile` should actually be sending 'index.js' instead of 'index.html'? I did try that too but the page was still blank.

Any other pointers would be greatly appreciated as I am not sure I understand where I'm going wrong.

Thank you!

Project code can be found at https://github.com/windwardpassage/ubcplanner

Heroku: https://ubcplanner4.herokuapp.com/

**Folder structure**

```
.
├── client
│   ├── App.css
│   ├── App.js
│   ├── index.js
│   ├── public
│   │   └── index.html
│   └── src
│       └── Folders of components, stores, images, etc.
├── package.json
└── server.js
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000">
    <title>React App</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <noscript>
      You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.
    </noscript>
    <div id="root"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**App.js**

```
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <MainHeader />
          <div className="ui-container">
              <Route path="/" exact component={ IndexPage } />
              <Route path="/signup" exact component={ SignupPage } />
              <Route path="/forgotpassword" exact component={ ForgotPasswordPage } />
          </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

**index.js**

```
const store = createStore(
    rootReducer,
    composeWithDevTools(applyMiddleware(thunk))
);

ReactDOM.render(
    <BrowserRouter>
        <Provider store={store}>
            <App />
        </Provider>
    </BrowserRouter>,
    document.getElementById("root")
);
registerServiceWorker();
```

**server.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const passport = require('passport');
const config = require('./config');
var cors = require('cors');
const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;

// connect to the database and load models
require('./server/models').connect(config.dbUri);

const app = express();

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  // Serve any static files
  app.use('client/public', express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/')));
  // Handle React routing, return all requests to React app
  app.get('*', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'client/public', 'index.html'));
      });
}

// tell the app to look for static files in these directories
//app.use(express.static('./server/static/'));
app.use(express.static('./client/dist/'));

// routes
const authRoutes = require('./server/routes/auth');
const apiRoutes = require('./server/routes/api');
app.use('/auth', authRoutes);
app.use('/api', apiRoutes);
app.use(cors());

// start the server
app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Listening on port ${port}`));
```

Comment: any fixes? let me know

Answer (score 0):

You have probably ignored the `public` directory in your `.gitignore` file.

This recently happened to me and i managed to solve it erasing the `public` directory from `.gitignore`.

Answer (score 0):

You are serving your static files before your routes. You need to serve your static files afterward. Try changing your server.js file to this:

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const passport = require('passport');
const config = require('./config');
var cors = require('cors');
const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;

// connect to the database and load models
require('./server/models').connect(config.dbUri);

const app = express();

// tell the app to look for static files in these directories
//app.use(express.static('./server/static/'));
app.use(express.static('./client/dist/'));

// routes
const authRoutes = require('./server/routes/auth');
const apiRoutes = require('./server/routes/api');
app.use('/auth', authRoutes);
app.use('/api', apiRoutes);
app.use(cors());

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  // Serve any static files
  app.use('client/public', express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/')));
  // Handle React routing, return all requests to React app
  app.get('*', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'client/public', 'index.html'));
      });
}

// start the server
app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Listening on port ${port}`));
```